Why does my MacBook Pro with a touchbar have a black screen but sounds still play?
One day my MacBook Pro was working and now its not. I was on a call with a friend playing Roblox, the computer was working perfectly and the screen was still on.
However when I went to use the restroom for a quick minute my MacBook screen was black, I thought that it just turned off after not being in use for awhile so I used the mouse to turn it back on but when I did this the screen would not budge it would stay black.
However, the weird part was that I could still hear audio from my friend, and I could even still talk to my friend using my microphone. But the screen was black and no matter what I pressed (mouse and keyboard) the screen would not budge.
I decided to turn it off and thought eventually the screen would be normal but when I tried to turn it on after turning it off for a good while nothing seemed to change.
When I turned it on the MacBook made the same turning on sound as it does however the screen was not pitch black it was more of a dark purple indicating that it was on.
However that was all the computer did, nothing happened after. The computer screen color still stayed that dark purple color. Another weird thing occurring was the fact that I could still charge my MacBook and the charging sound would still play.
It’s been about 2-3 days since the screen turned like this and nothing I do is working.

Have you tried augmenting luminosity? If it's at the lowest you can barely see anything.

Can you try an external monitor?
